# Problem with creation elements in Dash by cycles

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm creating a Python application with dash/plotly which works with dataframe with unknown number of columns, and I need to make some visualization which depends on this number. For example, I need to make a table which contains the same number of columns as my dataframe, and also I need the same number of graphs. I tried to do it with creating elements in cycles, but it didn't work. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty table, and an empty container. Run your callback to create the table as you need it, and update its `data` and `columns` properties, and just output all the graphs as `children` of the container.